# javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: java.lang.NullPointerException in my jsf web App

Tags: jsf-2, nullpointerexception, el

I am working on a dynamic Web Application and as a first step i want to use my jsf page to save a new Group in the DataBase .I am connecting to an Oracle 10g DataBase, working on eclipse Kepler, with Glassfish4 and using primefaces 4.0.This the StackTrace

```
                  2013-12-07T00:38:34.028+0100|Avertissement: #{groupeBean.createGroupe}: java.lang.NullPointerException
                 javax.faces.FacesException: #{groupeBean.createGroupe}: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:118)
at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
at javax.faces.component.UIData.broadcast(UIData.java:1108)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:646)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:260)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:188)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:191)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:168)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:189)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:288)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:206)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:136)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:114)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:838)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:113)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:115)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:55)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:135)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:564)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:544)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
           Caused by: javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: java.lang.NullPointerException
at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:101)
at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
... 35 more
         Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.portail.dao.DaoGroupe.ajouter(DaoGroupe.java:21)
at com.portail.managedBeans.GroupeBean.createGroupe(GroupeBean.java:24)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:275)
at com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:304)
at org.jboss.weld.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:40)
at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:50)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:87)
... 36 more
```

This is the code of the managedBean

```
                @ManagedBean
                @ViewScoped
              public class GroupeBean {
               private Groupe newGroupe=new Groupe();
                public Groupe getNewGroupe() {
            return newGroupe;
               }
          public void setNewGroupe(Groupe newGroupe) {
      this.newGroupe = newGroupe;
            }
          private DaoGroupe gdao= new DaoGroupe();
        public void createGroupe()
          {
        gdao.ajouter(newGroupe);
            }}
```

This is the code of the Dao Class

```
            public class DaoGroupe {
private static final String JPA_UNIT_NAME="Portail";
private EntityManager entityManager;
protected EntityManager getEntityManager() {
    if (entityManager == null) {
        entityManager = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(
                JPA_UNIT_NAME).createEntityManager();
    }
    return entityManager;
}
 public   void ajouter(Groupe g)
    {
        EntityTransaction tx = entityManager.getTransaction();
        tx.begin();
        entityManager.persist(g);
        tx.commit();}}
```

And this is the insert tab in my jsf page

```
                  <p:tab title="Groupe">
            <h:form>
                <h:panelGrid columns="2">
                    <h:outputText value="Nom : *" />
                    <p:inputText value="#{groupeBean.newGroupe.nom}" required="true"
                        label="nomgrp" validatorMessage="Nom de Groupe Obligatoire" />
                        <h:outputText value="Numéro : *" />
                    <p:inputText value="#{groupeBean.newGroupe.idGroupe}" required="true"
                        label="numgrp" validatorMessage="Numéro de Groupe Obligatoire" />
                </h:panelGrid>
                <p:commandButton value="Ajouter"
                    style="width:205px;margin-left:10%"
                    action="#{groupeBean.createGroupe}" />
            </h:form>

        </p:tab>
```

Comment: You're using GlassFish which supports EJBs out the box. Why are you still manually creating the entity manager and manually managing transactions? This is painful. Just use an EJB and you'll end up with 2-3 times less code than you now have because GlassFish will then automatically do injection and transaction management.

Comment: This is actually a university project, and i need to build the project from the scratch and view that i am a beginner , my professor gave me a model of a project and i should follow on it to finish the project before the deadline

Comment: Understandable. That's actually a good thing, you'll in the future better understand what boilerplate/mess the EJBs can take away from you. Good luck :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get a NullPointerException in your DaoGroupe-Class within the method `ajouter`. 
I guess the `entityManager.getTransaction()` is the reason, because the entityManager is not filled anywhere. Replacing it with using your `getEntityManager()`-method might be a first point to start debugging from.

```
EntityTransaction tx = getEntityManager().getTransaction();
```

Hope it helps...